# validation for multidimensional array

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I am sending an `array` from the front to backend. The array looks like this

```
array:1 [
"input" => array:9 [
"parameters" => array:2 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "name" => "cciaa"
    "value" => "VT"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [
    "name" => "nrea"
    "value" => "166066"
  ]
]
"token_utente" => "7e407066-1c6a-11ec-9bbe-0aae38056063"
"partita_iva" => "na"
"codice_fiscale" => "na"
"client_id" => null
"codici_servizi" => array:1 [
  0 => "sv_ricerca_impresa_base"
]
"id_richiesta_padre" => 0
"document_type" => "1"
"encoding" => "0"
]
]
```

I am trying to validate it using laravel 8 validation method.

```
    $validated = $request->validate ([
        'input.partita_iva'       => 'required',
        'input.codice_fiscale'    => 'required',
        'input.parameters[0].value'   => 'required',
        'input.parameters[1].value'   => 'required',
    ]);
```

Problem is that i am not able to validate the last two elements `ccia` and `nrea`. How can I do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk symbol (*) is used to check values in the array. You can try this:

```
$validated = $request->validate ([
   'input.partita_iva'       => 'required',
   'input.codice_fiscale'    => 'required',
   'input.parameters.*.value'   => 'required',
   'input.parameters.*.name'   => 'required',
]);
```